# Are clones allowed to retire?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, clones

In *Star Wars: The Clone Wars*, clone troopers are created to be the Republic's foot soldiers in the war.  The season 2 episode *The Deserter* implied that troopers can't just go AWOL.  But do they have some limited tour of duty they need to fulfill, and then they can retire?  Or are they soldiers for life?

Comment: I'd imagine not many live to old age, but its funny to imagine a decrepit clone sitting behind a desk somewhere. Or are the programed to die before they become too frail to fight?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Season 2 of *Star Wars Rebels*, episodes 1 and 2 feature three Kaminoan clones that retired: Captain Rex (from 501st Legion), Commander Wolffe (from  104th Battalion), and Commando Clone Gregor.

All three live together on/in an old RT-TT on Seelos.

Comment: They had no other choice because The Galactic Empire had discontinued The Clone Army. This isn't the correct answer.

Answer (score 15):

They are soldiers for life. Pretty much all the surviving Jango-Fett based caminoan clones were serving as Imperial Stormtroopers, even when they became a minority among non-clones and non-Fett clones in the latter days of the Empire.

There were SOME clones who kinda-retired - one example was a sleeper cell of Soonier Fel clones ([Carib Devist](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Carib_Devist)) in Zahn's Thrawn trilogy, who basically went native and became farmers - though they did come out of retirement to help Han Solo during battle for Bothawui. So if you're asking whether they were psychologically capable, then yes. But that was not the Master Plan for them.

Comment: In Wookiepedia, it states that the accelerated aging that allowed clones to become full-grown adults in a compressed period actually sped up as they got older, meaning they'd have very short lifespans compared to normal humans.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté - this comment probably should be made into an answer to my related question: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7261/what-were-the-natural-lifespans-of-camino-and-spaarti-clones

Comment: I think that "soldiers for life" is something of an incomplete answer.  After all, nobody would have much use for a 90-year-old soldier.  In which case, the answer could be that very, very, *very* few of them made it to old age.  Oddly few, it seems.  So then the question is whether they were *allowed* to make it to old age.  Which could mean they were put to death legally, or, say, sent on some sort of suicide mission when they got old enough.  Whichever way, simply being "soldiers for life" doesn't quite put the question to rest.

Answer (score 4):

In Star Wars:Battlefront II, the main character is a clone trooper who served in the Grand Army of the Republic, and later the Imperial military, more specifically the noted 501st stoormtrooper legion. Throughout his journal entries, it shows that he, along with other members of the legion, participated in some of the more famous battles during the Clone Wars, the Imperial Period, and the Galactic Civil War. It is stated at the end of the game that this particular unit is the Retired Clone Trooper, thus signifying that if they lived long enough, and survived past the Battle of Endor, clone troopers were allowed to leave active duty and live out the rest of their natural life.

Comment: The article can be viewed at http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Retired_clone_trooper