# What were the natural lifespans of Kamino and Spaarti clones?

Tags: star-wars, clones

If said clones were not killed in battles, what was the average life expectancy of both Kamino-grown, Fett-type clones and Spaarti technology clones?

I'd expect it to be less than humans, due to rapid maturation (10 years to full maturity for Kamino ones, and 1 year for Spaarti), but would like some canonically-sourced details.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [Wookieepedia page on cloning](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cloning#Reign_of_the_Empire):

> Although the exact rate at which clones aged is unknown, it appears to be nearly twice as fast a natural-born Human and it is theorized that this rate increased as clones grew older—especially under stress, thus leading to a dramatic shortening of the clones' life expectancy

To be honest, this makes very little sense to me, since most humans peak in athletic and mental function between the ages of 20 and 30. With the clone troopers it takes them 10 years to reach a mental/physical age of 20. But then, even with minimal increase in their accelerated aging, it takes them only 5 years to reach the effective age of 30, at which point they'd be considered old-timers as front-line soldiers (average age of front-line soldiers in Vietnam was 20~22 years old).

So it takes them 10 years to reach peak form, and then they only have 5 years of actual combat duty during their physical peak. And then less than 5 years later, they're effectively 40-years-old.

But assuming this 2x aging speed is correct, then they'd probably live for a maximum of 50~55 years, I'm guessing. Though they'd probably have to retire from the military before their 25th birthday (having only served 15 years in the military).

Comment: "In World War II, the average age of the combat soldier was 26. In Vietnam, it was 19" - Paul Hardcastle, song called "19".

Comment: @aquaherd: That's what I was initially going to write actually, but then I couldn't find any solid sources to back up that figure, and all of the age statistics on casualties pointed to a higher figure. Though it could be because it takes ~2 years for a new recruit to actually get killed.

Comment: In WWI the average age for a soldier was even higher. This past century saw a massive dismissal of older and willing men for combat that had never happened before.

Answer (score 5):

Well, [Joruus C'baoth](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Joruus_C%27baoth) was created around 27 BBY, aged to an adult human (aged to the real Jorus C'baoth's age) and still lived until several years after the battle of Endor.

He was a Spaarti clone.

He did not appear to be near his natural death when he was killed, nor did he seem to believe he would die any time soon.

It's therefore likely that Spaarti clones will age at a normal rate after their rapid-growth period.

I have no similar data for Kaminoan clones, however it is not difficult to believe that, if the Spaarti clones can age at a normal rate after maturation, the Kaminoans would be able to do the same with theirs, or possibly even slow their rate of aging.

There's also scattered references to surviving clone troopers being active Stormtroopers through the battle of Endor at least.  The Empire wouldn't keep them as active troops if they couldn't do the job.

Therefore, it's logical to assume that clones have at LEAST the normal lifespan, starting from when they reach the desired age (and the rapid aging is ceased).

Comment: Joruus was a clone of a pretty powerful Jedi (and Jedi himself). So I am not sure his lifespan was supposed to be close to a random human. Also, Spaarti lifespan under your theory would be 19 years less than typical human, right (they mature to 20 in 1 year)?

Comment: @DVK: Right, unless they were modified to age more slowly after maturity.

Comment: @DVK - another example of a Spaarti clone with a seemingly normal lifespan was Grodin Tierce in the Hand of Thrawn duology. In those same books, there were numerous Spaarti clones of Baron Soontir Fel who had been left on planets to age normally.

Answer (score 0):

In the novels it's stated that they were programmed to age at an accelerated rate, although it doesn't state the rate. There were live Kamino clones well after Yavin as Boba Fett is still alive in a village and meets then the legacy series. Not consistent source material.

Comment: Hi, welcome ot Sci-Fi.SE... Can you provide a source or excerpt from the novels to show 'they were programmed to age at an excel a rated rate' please?

Comment: I think Boba would be a poor example. Jango had him created specifically for him to raise as a son, so his programming was likely set to age at a normal human rate.

Comment: @Irishpanda In fact in the movie they mention it explicitly that Boba Fett was set to age at the natural human rate.

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but one that still comes up periodically.

Clones seem engineered to age at roughly double the rate their entire lives, as seen in Star Wars: Rebels.  Kanan Jarrus, who canonically is 1 year *older* than Captain Rex, is seen as a young man while Rex & Friends look far older.

So the better question is what is the average lifespan of a human in Star Wars.  Leland CHee has stated that while in Legends the average lifespan was stated to be 100-120 years old, new Canon has changed that to match "Real World" of an average of 71 years old (with obvious exceptions for individuals).

"Respect to the humans' lifespan in the Star Wars universe, in Star Wars Legends originally established that humans lived longer than in the real-world largely as they didn't have to take into account the actors getting older. However, in the new canon, Holocron continuity database keeper Leland Chee has stated that humans lived the same real-world average lifespan, which is estimated to be 71 years old. "

So figure a Clone who survived the Clone Wars could expect to live anywhere from 35-45 years or so, depending on medical care and the like.

Answer (score -3):

Well clones from the clone wars fought well into the battle of hoth at least, so assuming they continued to age at 2x speed they would be well over 60 years old by the time they fought at hoth. Which means they most likely don't age at double the rate. Otherwise we got us some bad-a grandpas.

Comment: Source for this? Updated canon indicates the Empire started to phase out clones at the end of the Clone Wars and used a volunteer force going forward.