# Years after Order 66 was initiated, if a clone saw a rogue Jedi, would they have to kill them? Or could they let them live?

Tags: star-wars, clones

For instance, if a clone was stranded on a planet during Order 66 and eventually found their way off the planet and then one day saw a rogue Jedi, would they have to kill them?

Comment: Order 66 is a standing order. Since, to the best of my knowledge the order is never rescinded, in strict legal terms they would be expected to carry it out.

Comment: I think the clone would be more concerned about keep himself alive rather than killing a Jedi.  It's difficult enough for an entire squad of clone troopers to kill a single Jedi, a single clone against a single Jedi would be suicide for said clone.  But more to the point, I have to agree with Richard, it's a standing order.

Answer (score 5):

Order 66 is a standing order that was given to clone troopers. Their obedience is controlled by a voice-activated biochip that overrides their personal opinions about their Jedi commanders. Any clone trooper told to execute [Order 66](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Order_66/Canon) will presumably carry it out to the best of their ability, regardless of personal risk, for the remainder of their lives.

Since to the best of my knowledge the order was never rescinded, you would expect a clone trooper to attempt to carry it out 5, 10 or 30 years later. Not only would they have a legal responsibility to do so as long (for the remainder of the terms as soldiers of the Grand Army) but they would also have an inbuilt desire to do so as long as their biochips remained active.

That said, since clones are [very short-lived](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7261/what-were-the-natural-lifespans-of-kamino-and-spaarti-clones), you'd expect those who'd explicitly been given the order to be dead within a few years anyway.

---

If they were incommunicado (or maintaining radio silence) at the time Order 66 was given, they wouldn't know to act upon it until they were advised that the Order was in effect, either by hearing a recording of Palpatine's order or having been given the order by a superior officer.

Comment: Clones are short-lived? How come Boba lived so long, then?

Comment: @user38502 - **OBI-WAN :** *Unaltered?* **LAMA SU** : *Pure genetic replication. No tampering with the structure to make it more docile... and **no growth acceleration**...*

Comment: @user38502 the clones had an acccelerated aging which boba did not have (see star wars 2 attack of the clones there it is mentioned). If I remember correctly the clone troopers age at a rate of 2 years for 1 year due to the accelerated aging which was used to create them so fast

Answer (score 5):

**In the new Disney canon**, the answer is unknown as of yet, since the exact text of the order is unknown and no clone trooper examples have been shown

---

**In the Legends canon**, the answer is "no". The exact text of the order from Karen Traviss' book "Republic Commando: True Colors" is:

> Order 66: In the event of Jedi officers acting against the interests of the Republic, and after receiving specific orders verified as coming directly from the Supreme Commander (Chancellor), GAR commanders will remove those officers by lethal force, and command of the GAR will revert to the Supreme Commander (Chancellor) until a new command structure is established.

The order thus was not against ALL Jedi, but only the Jedi Generals commanding the clone troopers specifically. As such, a rogue random Jedi wouldn't be affected by Order 66 directly .